# How to change a job schedule (date/time) in Rundeck from another application?

Tags: rundeck

Does Rundeck have an API to dynamically change schedule? If not is there any other way to do the same?

a. POST .../api/21/job/[ID]/run 
{
    "runAtTime":"new-date/time"
}

- Schedules the job at new-date/time and runs the job but old schedule does not change.

b. POST /api/21/job/[ID]/execution/enable 
- Only enables scheduling

Rundeck API page: https://rundeck.org/docs/api/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Think I have found an API:
POST  .../api/14/project/[PROJECT-NAME]/jobs/import?dupeOption=update 
Add a block for new schedule:

```
<schedule>
    <month month='...'>
    <time hour='12' minute='45' seconds='15'>
    <weekday day='...' />
    <year year='...' />
 </schedule>
```

To get current details of the job call 
GET ...api/14/project/[PROJECT-NAME]/jobs/export
This will return all jobs under PROJECT.
 We will have to extract block for our job.

Points to note:
- content-type must be application/xml
- uuid must be specified in POST
- dupeOption=update must be specified a parameter; else Rundeck will create a duplicate job instead of updating our job